# Получение данных в один объект redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hook

Нужно объединить несколько данных redux store в один объект, например есть такое хранилище
[image: Есть хранилище], но проблема в том, что он должен быть в одном объекте, но я не понимаю как это сделать, то есть должно быть что то такое
[image: Результат]

то есть объединено допустим в api.

В первом случае заполнение store делается таким образом

**authors.js** - reducer

```js
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    isLoaded: false,
  };
  
  const authors = (state = initialState, action) => {
    
    if (action.type === 'SET_AUTHORS') {
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
      };
    }
    return state;
  };
  
  export default authors;
```

action, items получает из axios.get запроса на сервер.

```js
export const setAuthors = (items) => ({
    type: 'SET_AUTHORS',
    payload: items,
})
```

для книг и жанров аналогичный код.
Как надо поменять код, чтобы получилось как на 2 картинке?

Comment: вам нужна такая структура именно в хранилище или в каком то месте кода?

Comment: Мне нужно получать доступ к хранилищу через единственную подписку на хранилище (useSelector), а не отдельно через 3. С 1 картинкой прийдется ставить 3 отдельных подписки, что на удобстве и производительности.